# check if a string contains character except the ones in a given string python

Tags: python

How can I check if a string (`string1`) contains characters except the ones in the following string (`seq_letters`):

```
string1 = 'SEQ'

seq_letters = 'ATCGRYMKSWHBVDN'
```

`E` and `Q` are not in seq_letters.

Comment: You can use a regex with negative group: `re.fullmatch(r'[^%s]*' % seq_letters, string1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `set.difference`

```
string1 = 'SEQ'
seq_letters = 'ATCGRYMKSWHBVDN'

print(set(string1).difference(seq_letters))
```

**Output:**

```
{'E', 'Q'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = 'SEQ'
seq_letters = 'ATCGRYMKSWHBVDN'
result = []
for i in string1:
    if i not in seq_letters:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```